# Let $v$ and $w$ be eigen vectors of $T$ corresponding to two distinct eigen values $ \lambda _1$ and $ \lambda_ 2$ respectively

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Problem**:Let $v$ and $w$ be eigen vectors of $T$ corresponding to two distinct eigen values $ \lambda _1$ and $ \lambda_ 2$  respectively
>
> Then which of the following is true ?
>
> $1)$ For non zero scalars $\alpha_ 1$ , $\alpha_ 2$, the vector  $\alpha_ 1v + \alpha_ 2 w$ is not eigen vector of $T$
>
> $2)$ For all  scalars $\alpha_ 1$ , $\alpha_ 2$, the vector  $\alpha_ 1v + \alpha_ 2 w$ is not eigen vector of $T$
>
> $3)$  $\alpha_ 1v + \alpha_ 2 w$ is eigen vector of $T$, if $\alpha_ 1 = \alpha_ 2$
>
> $4)$  $\alpha_ 1v + \alpha_ 2 w$ is eigen vector of $T$, if $\alpha_ 1 = -\alpha_ 2$
>
> **Solution**:

I know about eigen values and eigen functions

But I have no idea about this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Tv=\lambda_{1}v$ and $Tw=\lambda_{2}w$ with $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$. Since $T$ is (presumably)
linear, $$T\left(\alpha_{1}v+\alpha_{2}w\right)=\alpha_{1}Tv+\alpha_{2}Tw=\alpha_{1}\lambda_{1}v+\alpha_{2}\lambda_{2}w.$$
Since $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$ are distinct, we cannot write
this as $\lambda\left(\alpha_{1}v+\alpha_{2}w\right)$. (1) is true.

Take $\alpha_{1}=0$. Then clearly $\alpha_{1}v+\alpha_{2}w$ **is**
an eigenvector of $T$. (2) is false.

(3) and (4) are false by (1).

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ act on what you're asking about. For example, what is equal to $T(\alpha_1 v + \alpha_2 w)$? You can simplify this expression.

Answer (score 0):

$Tv = \lambda_1 v$ and $Tw = \lambda_2 w$.

It follows: $T(\alpha_1 v + \alpha_2 w) = \alpha_1 \lambda_1 v + \alpha_2 \lambda_2 w$ . Since $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are distinct, $\alpha_1 v + \alpha_2 w$ cannot be an eigenvector for all non-zero scalars $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$.

Hence, the first option is true.